# Копирование химических формул из .docx

Tags: python, docx

Как с помощью библиотеки python-docx извлечь химическую формулу из текста ячейки таблицы и перенести ее в другую таблицу?

**Если копировать, как текст**, то **нет разницы** между **цифрой в верхнем, нижнем** или **обычном регистре**

Пример таблицы
[image: Пример]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В версии 0.8.6 [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io) этот функционал отсутствует, даже нужного пространства имен нет и нигде нет упоминания нужных тегов, то есть нет ни единого упоминания возможности работы с математическими элементами. Формулы из Word, например, в сыром виде выглядят как-то так. Исходная формула: e<sup>x</sup>=sin(x)

docx:

```
<m:oMathPara>
    <m:oMath>
        <m:sSup>
            <m:sSupPr>
                <m:ctrlPr>
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/><w:i/>
                        <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
                    </w:rPr>
                </m:ctrlPr>
            </m:sSupPr>
            <m:e>
                <m:r><w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/>
                    <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
                    </w:rPr>
                    <m:t>e</m:t>
                </m:r></m:e>
                <m:sup>
                <m:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/>
                    <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
                </w:rPr><m:t>x</m:t></m:r>
                </m:sup>
            </m:sSup>
            <m:r><w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/>
                <w:lang w:val="en-US"/></w:rPr>
                <m:t>=isin(x)</m:t>
            </m:r>
        </m:oMath>
</m:oMathPara>
```

То есть вы можете попробовать спуститься в самый адок и обращаться с docx, как с набором XML документов. И вам необходимо найти в параграфе, в ячейке, где хотите нужный тег и потом вставить также в новый параграф, ячейку, куда хотите. Вот такой вот примерчик приведу. Он копирует формулу из одного документа, в пустой другой документ. В исходном документе нет ничего, кроме этой формулы. Однако, я бы уверенно себя не чувствовал на этом пути, даже если простой пример и работает. Также вместо тупого итерирования вы можете отыскать нужный элемент с тегом `<oMathPara>` в пространстве `{"m": xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math"}`. Итак:

```
import docx


d = docx.Document("formula_test.docx")

new_doc = docx.Document()
new_para = new_doc.add_paragraph()
new_para_elem = new_para._element

para_with_formula = d.paragraphs[0]

# Это уже объект типа CT_P, родителем которого является lxml.Element
elem = para_with_formula._element
# Пространство имен `m` xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math"
tmp_ns = {"m": "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math"}

math_tag_with_namespace = "{" + tmp_ns["m"] + "}oMathPara"

for i in elem.getiterator():
    if i.tag == math_tag_with_namespace:
        print("OH! A formula!")
        new_para_elem.append(i)

new_doc.save("NEW_DOC.docx")
```

Как результат - в новом документе исходная формула.

Comment: можно попробовать ячейку таблицы целиком скопировать.

Comment: Путем присвоения ячейке в новой таблице  соответствующей ячейки из старой таблицы - не работает  @jfs

Comment: @РусланВергунов, если вы хотите обойтись без работы с XML, и вам подойдет копировать напрямую таблицу целиком или отдельные ячейки целиком (не изолируя только формулы в них), то можете создать отдельный вопрос на эту тему - копировать можно по-разному, с разным, соответственно, результатом.

Comment: @РусланВергунов "не работает" не информативно. Слово "присвоение" в вашем комментарии намекает, что возможно неправильно ваш код *копирует* ячейку (беглый взгляд на библиотеку говорит, что использовать её для разных задач, не глядя на исходный код и xml, которым она оперирует, достаточно тяжело).  Вы хотите узнать "как скопировать ячейку таблицы целиком с сохранением форматирования из одного документа в другой" или целиком всю таблицу или только формулу в выбранной ячейке?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/659534/python-docx-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B   -@jfs