# python-docx Копировать ячейку таблицы

Tags: python, docx

Необходимо копировать ячейку таблицы со всем содержимым из одного файла в ячейку таблицы в другом файле.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from docx import Document

oldDocument = Document("d:/first.docx")

newDocument = Document()
f = oldDocument.tables[9].rows[1].cells[1]
table = newDocument .add_table(rows=1, cols=1)
table.rows[0].cells[0] = f
newDocument .save("d:/2.docx")
```

Пример таблицы.В ячейке может быть текст или изображение

[image: Пример]

При запуске кода возникает ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/������/Desktop/Tasks/Tasks.py", line 9, in <module>
    table.rows[0].cells[0] = im
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? Не копируется или ошибка какая-то возникает?

Comment: @gil9red  Возникает ошибка TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Добавьте ошибку с стеком к вопросу

Comment: `cells` возвращает тип `tuple` -- это по сути неизменяемый список, похоже в этой библиотеке нужно другим способом менять значения в ячейках таблицы

Comment: Другим значит не получится т.к. доступен будет только текст. Изображения получить не удастся

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43669892/4279

Comment: Думаю, нужно копать в сторону `add_table`, `add_column`, `add_row` и т.п. Как мне кажется, нужно именно в сторону `add_row`. То есть как-то так: `table.add_row(cells=cell)`

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя просто скопировать какой либо объект, считав его из одного документа и записать его в другой. Объекты `python-docx` это объекты оборачивающие XML, которые представляют определённые структуры: таблицы, ячейки и т.д..

Надо считать содержимое документа источника, затем создавать требуемую структуру включая, таблицу, ячейки и параграфы в целевом документе, помещая туда ранее считанные данные.