# Копирование элемента с помощью python-docx

Tags: python, xml, ms-word, docx

У меня стоит задача скопировать параграф в котором имеются числа в верхнем регистре как в формулах из одного документа в генерируемый.

Необходимо как то либо перенести форматирование ( но я читал что python-docx вообще не поддерживает такие штуки)

Возможно просто взять объект XML кода и вставить его в нужном месте (я думал создать новый параграф а потом просто на его место вставить XML код нужного)

[image: Формулы]

Я опирался на следующий [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/656319/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB-%D0%B8%D0%B7-docx) 
Пробовал различные варианты:

```
new_p._element=p._element
```

или

```
new_p._element.append(p._element)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для копирования параграфа из одного документа в другой с сохранением форматирования нам необходимо по факту взять кусок XML и вставить его в другом документе.

Для этого нам необходимо:

1. Создать новый параграф в который будем копировать

   ```
   # p - новый параграф куда копируем    
   p = new_doc.add_paragraph()
   ```
2. Берём текущий параграф и получаем доступ к атрибуту _element.
   Когда мы получаем доступ к атрибуту _element мы уже находимся внутри Параграфа а именно внутри тэга `<p></p>` в XML разметке

   ```
   elem = old_p._element
   ```
3. Нам остаётся в цикле обойти все подтэги внутри старого параграфа и скопировать их в новый.

   ```
   p = doc.add_paragraph()
   p_el=p._element

   elem = old_p._element
   for i in elem.getchildren():
           p_el.append(i)
   ```